# Login failed to local SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, ssms, local

I've seen a lot of questions on here about being unable to find a local instance of SQL Server.

I can find it; I just can't figure out what it wants for authentication.

Windows authentication doesn't work and I can't leave the user name and password blank for SQL Server Management Studio

The error I'm getting is "Login failed for user 'blah\blah\' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 184566"

How can I reset my login password or find out what the username and password are?  Is there a default?

Comment: Have you tried using the service account credentials? You can verify which account is being used as the service account by viewing the server properties in SQL Server Configuration Manager. You should also post detail about the error you're getting. For example: it could alternatively be an issue of a user-default DB having been dropped - in which case it's not a problem with auth.

Comment: I'm not seeing any properties for servers in the SQL Server Configuration Manager besides "Force Protocol Encryption" and "Trust Server Certificate".  The error I'm getting is simply "Login failed for user 'blah\blah\' (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 184566"

Comment: Sounds like you're in the `SQL Server Network Configuration` section. Try going to `SQL Server Services` right-click `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`  then select `Properties` and go to the `Log On` tab (note that the name of your instance may not be the default `(MSSQLSERVER)`).

Comment: There's nothing under SQL Server Services or SQL Server Network Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the the logins on SSMS using initially the `sa` login. Depending on the settings you can set up either Windows authentication for individual users or specific username and password.

Answer (score 1):

I can answer what happened in my scenario.  I delete a database, which happened to be the default database for my account login.  I was able to get my connection working again by logging into SSMS "As Admin" with 'Login2' and using that login to change my default database for the other login, 'Login1'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

if windows auth does not work, you should probably try using sql server auth and login with your SA password.  SA is the built in administrator account.  once you are logged in, then you can start working with whatever other logins are there and you can probably also set up windows auth as well - google search results abound, give it a try

if you can't remember your sa password, you should be able to reset it locally from command line, i believe osql is the program you want to run.  google for "forgot sa password"

let us know how it goes!

Comment: So far with the suggestions online, I run into the same wall.  Changing it from command line, etc; i just get "login incorrect". I might not have admin permissions on this machine, but I can change ODBC connections and other things so I think I have admin permission.  I may have to just find whoever installed it or our Point of Contact for the application.

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same issue and solved it with a different approach. First, go to the Sql Server Configuration Manager and check whether the SQL server Log on as is set to LocalSystem.
[image]

If not then go to properties -> Log on -> Built-in account -> Local System. Now try to login to the local DB from SSMS.